# Touchable is not clickable when view is absolute position in RN

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to keep a few buttons one on the top left and others on right side. But touchable actions is not working for right side views.
I want to make two side clickable. But only one side is working.
What would be the issue?

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', justifyContent: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 12 }}>
   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={...}> Right icon 1 </TouchableOpacity>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={...}> Right icon 2 </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={...} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 10}}> Back </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: might be `position:'absolute'` and `zIndex:10` is causing issue. this button might be overlapping on others. can you check  that?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani Yes. left button is overlapping on it. If I try to bring right side view on top, left side is not clickable. Is there any best way rather than giving static position value?

Comment: so you want back button on left and others on right side ?

Comment: Using maxWidth, flex, width combination may solve the problem with absolute element or you need to change the structure of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alignSelf` property rather then absolute position,

```
<View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        paddingHorizontal: 12
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row-reverse",alignSelf:"flex-end" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity> Right icon 1 </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity> Right icon 2 </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignSelf:"flex-start"}}> Back </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Note(changes) : removed `justifyContent` from container, removed `position` & `zIndex` from back button and added `alignSelf` to both childs.

Comment: I tried this on my own use case. I managed to align the button correctly, while it create some challenges because the rest of the content depends on it, but by the end, the overflow stays unclickable.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingHorizontal: 12 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("back")} >
          <Text> Back </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row-reverse', flex: 2 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("icon1")}>
          <Text>Right icon 1 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("icon2")}>
          <Text> Right icon 2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
```